# Is it possible to run GOG Galaxy inside Steam via steam-store application?

Tags: steam, gog, gog-galaxy

I know that on Steam it is possible to run non-steam applications and games via "Add non-steam game", but I'm running Steam via Geforce Now service where this way doesn't work. You can add non-steam games but you can't succesfully execute them. I have two questions then:

1. Is it possible to run GOG client as a Steam app (I couldn't find on Steam Store)?
2. Is it possible to run GOG client using some Steam app available on the store - maybe some kind of file manager or something like that?

I was trying to find some apps to do this but could't find anything resembling general launcher or file manager. Maybe I was looking in wrong places.

Comment: If you do somehow figure out how to do this, they will likely patch it out very quickly, as I imagine there would be licensing issues with allowing you to stream games that you didn't buy via Steam.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, No. You can't run GOG Galaxy from Steam. You must download GOG Galaxy and run it as a program of it's own. [Here is where you can download it.](https://www.gog.com/galaxy)